# Sonata: translations with parameters

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I can't seem to be able to use translations with variables in Sonata as I do in normal symfony controllers.

In my controller:

```
$this->setSonataFlashSuccess(
    $this->get('translator')->trans('flash_create_success', [
        '%link%' => 'abcd',
        '%id%' => '1234'
    ])
);
```

My template:

```
{{ message|trans|raw }}
```

My translations file 'SonataAdminBundle.yml':

```
flash_create_success: Created with success: <a href="%link%">#%id%</a>
```

The rendered HTML:

```
Created with success: <a href="%link%">#%id%</a>
```

So the translation worked but not the replacement of the expressions Link and Id. Is there something especial about translations in Sonata? Everything works fine in the rest of the app.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a translations file, you have to name it differently than the original (e.g. `admin_messages.[langage].yml`), otherwise the original `SonataAdminBundle.[locale].yml` will be used.

So, you should create a file in your bundle like :

```
# YourBundle/Resources/translations/admin_messages.en.yml`
flash_create_success: Created with success: <a href="%link%">#%id%</a>
```

And specify it in your controller :

```
$this->get('translator')->trans(
    'flash_create_success', 
    array(
        '%link%' => 'abcd',
        '%id%' => '1234'
    ), 
    'admin_messages', // By default looks for a "messages.[_locale].yml"
);
```

Note that you don't need to translate the message one more time in your template, as it is already translated in your controller.